Run playwright fullscreen and without any infobar at the top saying "Chrome is being controlled..."
I have the following code running the lastest version of Playwright and playwright-go
browser, err := pw.Chromium.LaunchPersistentContext(userDataDir, playwright.BrowserTypeLaunchPersistentContextOptions{
    Headless:          playwright.Bool(false),
    Viewport: nil,
    Args: []string{
        "--kiosk",
        "--start-maximized",
        //"--fullscreen",
        "--app=https://youtube.com",
        "--no-zygote",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-infobars",
        "--hide-scrollbars",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--ignore-deafault-args=enable-automation",
    },
})

However, it does not open full screen and there is a info bar in to top saying that is being controlled.
How to remove the infobar and make it true fullscreen?

You can't remove that infobar

Can I make it fullscreen, so the info bar will be hidden?
